# int equivalent of .charAt() method

Tags: java

What's the int equivalent of the char@ method? For example

```
int[] numbers {23,321,12,124,1324,1234,54,655,765,6,54,7};
//if the digit 5 is found,
{
continue;
}
```

Comment: what method do you mean excatly? String#charAt() ?

Comment: I mean the char@ method in strings. Can we do the same with intigers?

Comment: `numbers[5]` do you mean this?

Comment: @wormwood What are you actually trying to achieve? Forget about `charAt` for now, just explain the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Do you want to check whether the int array has the number 5 in it?

Comment: If a number in an array contains "5" in it, sutch as 15, 25, 50 etc the continue statement will be executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
        {
            if (String.valueOf(numbers[index]).contains("5"))
            {
                System.out.println("Yes");
                continue;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well:

```
 for(int n : numbers){
   if(String.valueOf(n).contains("5"))
   continue;
}
```